# "Blacklist" or remove certain things from a return in a Python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-requests

I am writing a Python script that collects class information using a Course API. It has two functions: `get_schools` and `get_classes`. The `get_schools` function fetches a JSON file from the API and creates a list of different departments:

```
def get_schools(term_id):
    data = request('schools', term_id)
    return list(map(lambda school: {
        'id': school['id'],
        'name': school['name']
    }, data))
```

So the returned list is:

```
[{"id":"A", "name":"Department A"}, {"id": "B", "name": "Department B"}.......]
```

The `get_classes` function then uses the departments above to retrieve the specific classes and write them to a JSON file. The issue is that some of the departments have superfluous classes I don't need that are drastically lengthening the time the script takes to run.

Is there way to "blacklist" certain departments in the `get_schools` function to stop this from happening? So it skips over or removes "Department C" or "Department F" but leaves everything else in. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a department blacklist (use a `set` for best performance) and then [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) `data` based on the blacklist:

```
def get_schools(term_id):
    blacklist = set(['Department C', 'Department F'])
    data = request('schools', term_id)
    return list(map(lambda school: {
        'id': school['id'],
        'name': school['name']
    }, filter(lambda school: school['name'] not in blacklist, data)))
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks so much.

Comment: It will be faster to use sets in place of list for blacklisted departments. Sets takes O(1) time to check if an element is in it or not.